Does multiplying an exogenous variable reduce endogeneity?
Let $X$ be an endogenous variable, $Y$ be a non-negative exogenous variable, and $e$ the error term. Define $\operatorname{cov}(.,.)$ as the covariance. Then, $\operatorname{cov}(X,e) \neq 0$ and $\operatorname{cov}(Y,e) = 0$. Define $Z = XY$.
So, how to evaluate $\operatorname{cov}(Z,e)$? Is it greater than $\operatorname{cov}(X,e)$?
If I understand it correctly, assuming multivariate normality and following Bohrnstedt & Goldberger (1969) - equation (12), we have:
$\operatorname{cov}(Z,e)$ = $\operatorname{E}(Y)$ $\cdot$ $\operatorname{cov}(X,e)$
Here, as $Y$ in a non-negative than $E(Y) \geq 0$. Therefore, in this specific case, multiplying an exogenous variable would not reduce endogeneity unless $E(Y) = 0$. Is this correct? It seems counter-intuitive to me as we expect that multiplying by exogenous variables should reduce the $\operatorname{cov}(Z,e)$ compared to $\operatorname{cov}(X,e)$.
Reference: Bohrnstedt, George W., and Arthur S. Goldberger. “On the Exact Covariance of Products of Random Variables.” Journal of the American Statistical Association, vol. 64, no. 328, 1969, pp. 1439–42. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2286081.

This seems related, where the lack of third order moments in your formula should stem from multivariate normality: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044833/need-help-to-get-covxy-z Also, would it not reduce endogeneity as long as $E(Y)<1$? Finally, although that is not your question, if you have an exogenous $Y$, why not work with that instead of building $Z$? E.g. as an instrumental variable in a regression framework?

Thank you for your answer. You are correct; I may be assuming more information than I actually have. Are you suggesting that the third-order moment vanishes solely due to the assumption of multivariate normality? Regarding your question, the context is related to attempting to transform a time-invariant instrumental variable (the "Y" in my example) into a time-varying one.

As to the moments, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments. If it is just about making it time-varying, you could multiply it with some random, say AR(1), sequence---although that is admittedly unlikely to be a solution to your problem

Do you think that if I normalize the variable Y to lie between [0, 1], then I could claim that cov(Z, e) < cov(X, e)? I understand this may seem unconventional, but my intention is to reinforce the concept of exogeneity. Specifically, suppose I have a composite IV, Z, where X represents the time-varying component of Z that I believe to be "almost"-exogenous (pardon me for using this unusual concept). I intend to argue that by multiplying X by the time-invariant variable Y, which is clearly exogenous, I can create a "better" instrument Z compared to using only X. Does this make sense?

That sure sounds interesting. But I do not really yet understand what the variation in the data then is - IV using $Z$ identifies $Cov(Z,D)/Cov(Z,X)$ with $D$ the dependent variable (the usual notation $Y$ already being taken). If you only had time series variation in your data and $Y$ only takes one value over time, say $y$, then $Cov(Z,D)/Cov(Z,X)=$yCov(X,D)/yCov(X,X)$$ and you would be back at the original endogenous problem, no?

I have panel data and ultimately aim to employ an IV + fixed effects strategy. To maintain clarity, let's go back to conventional notation. I have proposed using a time-varying IV, denoted as $H$, to instrument for $X$ (endogenous). While the argument is convincing, it still generates some doubt. To address this suspicion, I plan to multiply $H$ by an unquestionably (let's assume) exogenous time-invariant IV, denoted as $W$. The resulting instrument is denoted as $Z$ = $H$ $\times$ $W$. That why I am trying to understand the behavior of $\operatorname{Cov}(Z,e)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(H,e)$.

OK. Indeed, this sounds like you would get a "more convincing", in the sense of more valid, IV this way. That being said, it is not automatically clear if that also leads to better estimates, as $W$ might be less strongly correlated with $X$, costing relevance and hence leading to less precise estimates.
